# Week/month calculation based on create date

Tags: sharepoint-designer, date-time

I am building a SharePoint designer worklfow (2010 mode). I want to be able to determine/calculate the week and month when a workflow is created and use this in the workflow itself.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn to use Calculated Columns

https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Weeknumber is a beast, see the example in the WeekDay Function

Month is `=MONTH( [YourDate] )`